# How to use Asian otf font in MPDF?

Tags: php, fonts, mpdf, truetype, asianfonts

I need to generate Pdfs in Asian languages, and I'm using MPdf.
Everything's fine when adding custom fonts for Latin languages.

However, for Asian languages I thought I would use `noto` font, but I get an *error saying the font contains postscript outline*. This font has `otf` format.
I understand `ttf` files do not contain those "postscript outlines" but I could not find a `ttf` version of `noto` font.

Any suggestions of how to resolve or better understand the problem would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

There are OTF fonts with TrueType and PostScript outlines. The latter are not supported in mPDF.

The error message was updated to be more understandable in the upcoming patch release.